# Hide and show with slide effect

Tags: jquery, slide, effect

I want to slide in a div from left and move the current to the right, just like in iOS where you go back and forward.

I tried this but doesn't seem work:

```
jQuery(".post .order").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).parents(".post-front")
            .hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
            .next(".post-back")
            .show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
```

markup:

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-front">
        <a href="#" class="next"></a>   
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="post-back">
        <a href="#" class="back"></a>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your _markup_ and specify what exactly _doesn't work_.

Comment: Consider sliding the outer container element instead of the individual elements. You can lay out the elements side-by-side, so that only one of them is visible, and then translate the container horizontally in order to "slide" various elements in and out.

Comment: is something like that http://www.ladehoffcondominios.com.br/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/FGGBH/1/)*** is a Live Demo. Is this something you are trying to achieve? Please comment.